# Azure Data Factory - Upsert to Oracle

Tags: oracle, azure-data-factory

I can read and write from an Oracle database using 'Copy Data' activity, but get a 'Unique Constraint Error' if trying to update an existing record in Oracle.

Is it possible to default the write behaviour to treat all records as Upserts, or, trigger a SP to merge the data?

*I did look at using Azure Data Factory 'dataflows' but don't seem to be able to specify Oracle DS as a Sink.*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oracle connector doesn't support upsert by now. Oracle as sink only support these properties:

[image]